# How do I make a list clickable?

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm currently working on [a pure CSS color palette](http://reversl.net/banner/) that needs to be a link. I've created this palette by using an unordered list, which I then wrapped in a `<a>` tag. I have a suspicion that this is not very semantic though. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="color-palette">
<a href="#">Modern Feminine</a>
<a href="#">
    <ul class="color-chips group">
        <li class="grey">#999999</li>
        <li class="slate">#666666</li>
        <li class="lilac">#99878D</li>
        <li class="blush">#7E4A5C</li>
        <li class="plum">#372129</li>
    </ul><!--.color-chips group-->
</a>
</div><!--.color-palette-->
```

**CSS**

```
.color-palette {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.color-chips {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.color-chips li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.color-chips li {
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a list inside an anchor.

You need to make each of the individual items in the list a seperate link.

```
<ul class="color-chips group">
        <li class="grey"><a href="">#999999</a></li>
        <li class="slate"><a href="">#666666</a></li>
        <li class="lilac"><a href="">#99878D</a></li>
        <li class="blush"><a href="">#7E4A5C</a></li>
        <li class="plum"><a href="">#372129</a></li>
    </ul><!--.color-chips group-->
```

If you don't need links because you're not actually linking to anything (i.e. you're performing on-the-page operations) simply remove the anchors all together. You don't need them when attaching your Javascript onclick events.

Comment: I should have explained it a little better. Basically clicking the palette will trigger changes to the page color styles. Maybe 'link' is the wrong terminology then?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="color-chips group">
    <li class="grey"><a href="javascript:;">#999999</a></li>
    <li class="slate"><a href="javascript:;">#666666</a></li>
    <li class="lilac"><a href="javascript:;">#99878D</a></li>
    <li class="blush"><a href="javascript:;">#7E4A5C</a></li>
    <li class="plum"><a href="javascript:;">#372129</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

What would you like to do after your click? Do you use javascript event when click is fired?

Comment: Clicking the palette will trigger new page styles based on the colors

Comment: Do the current answers satisfy your need?

Comment: So I think this is the solution but I'm not sure how to apply it in my case though http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already handling clicks with JS, I assume the anchor is purely cosmetic. In that case you can use CSS:

```
.color-chips:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```